# Index Path for the table view cell is not being accessible

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I am trying a new sample project and in that i'm adding a `table view` to a `ViewController` and on tap of each table view cell it is navigated to a detail view controller by making it a `push segue`.

In `prepareForSegue()` method,indexPath for the selected `tableViewCell` is retuned as nil.

Here's the method,

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("detail_segue", sender: self)
}

func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue?,sender: AnyObject!){

  if(segue!.identifier == "detail_segue"){
      var indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
      let detailViewController = segue!.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
          detailViewController.sampleDetail = samplesArray[indexPath!.row] as! Sample
    }
}
```

Let me know where i'm going wrong?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: can u pls add little  more code

Comment: You need to show `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` of table view delegate.

Comment: Its just a simple table view on a view controller and on tap of table view cell the page is navigated(with push segue) to another viewcontroller...Thats very basic.But what i'm confused is, why is that the indexPath is returned as nil???

Comment: @Desdenova: Can you please let me know what could be done in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`..Pl have a look on what i have done

Comment: It's possible that you are manually deselecting the row before calling the perform segue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
var index = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as UITableViewCell)!
```

I think maybe your tableviewcell.selectionStyle is None, so self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() will return nil because it is really have no selected row.

Comment: Yes i tried it... same outcome..as, "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" and selectionStyle is also set to Default..

Comment: In this case, you can past the indexPath when you call  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("detail_segue", sender: "yourIndexPath") and restore it at prepareForSegue like var indexPath = sender as NSIndexPath